# Native memory leak detection android

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms

Where can I find libc_malloc_debug_leak.so and libc_malloc_debug_qemu.so for different android versions (Ice cream sandwich, jelly bean, KitKat) and different devices (Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7, Nexus 10) ?

Answer (score 1):

Found them in the system-images that comes along with the Android SDK. I just extracted the system-images and found the .so's in the system/lib folder.